# Problema con update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, update

Tengo 2 controladores para hacer updates a diferentes tablas y tengo algunos problemas, uno es que cuando uso `route()` en el segundo controlador no me enlaza con las funciones dentro del controlador, y otra es que la funcion `update` no me esta funcionando y me da un error:

> Trailing data

Solo dice eso, sin nada más. Según el error esta en la función del `update`, este es el código del `update` y no lo veo mal, ¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,['DescEstado' => 'required']);
    Estado::find($id)->update($request->all());

    return redirect()
       ->route('sistema.index')
       ->with('success', 'Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
}
```

Comment: Parece que tu BD es Postgresql, que devuelve las fechas con milisegundos, [revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210872/5587982), quizá tengas que agregar un método de formateo de fecha en el modelo.

Comment: Lo hice y cambio el error a uno de "Datos inesperados encontrados" creo el problema es que cuando guardo uso $request-all() pero solo quiero actualizar 1 solo campo de la tabla

Comment: No sé, a ver si algún experto en Laravel te dice algo más concreto.

Comment: intentalo asi  `Estado::where('id',$id)->update($request->all());` o `Estado::where('id',$id)->update(['DescEstado' => $request->get('DescEstado')]);` donde el primer parametro en `where` y en `update` es el nombre del tabla [database queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#updates)

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad, me funciono de verdad gracias